# Picking the "server" in a Game Center match

Tags: ios, game-center

I am developing a social game that uses Game Center and had a question about informing one of the player's client that it will be used as the "server".  At first I thought to send a data packet to the GKPlayer which was returned with the method:
`- (void)chooseBestHostingPlayerWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(GKPlayer *player))completionHandler`
The only issue I can see with using this method is if it is possible for another player in a match to pick someone else who their client thinks would be the best "server".  At the moment I am assuming since this method is under GKMatch that it already takes into consideration all current players in the game and each application that runs this match should get the same GKPlayer object returned. Is this true?

Comment: Ever come to a decision on this?

Comment: I ended up creating my own backend system to handle matches but from what I tested the GKPlayer object returned was the same on all devices (Only tested up to 4 devices in a match).

Comment: We had to end up comparing playerIDs and selecting the lowest one. This method wasn't reliable it seemed

Answer (score 0):

All players in the match must call chooseBestHostingPlayerWithCompletionHandler, as per the documentation.  If that is done, all players receive the same answer: either a specific GKPlayer or nil.